# Module 'angular' has no exported member 'material'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i'm trying to use Angular 1 with Typescript. I'm using npm @types to fetch my type declaration files. Webstorm recognizes the type definitions, but when i run `tsc` the output is the following:

```
node_modules/@types/angular-material/index.d.ts(6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.
node_modules/@types/angular-ui-router/index.d.ts(6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.
src/core.config.ts(9,68): error TS2305: Module 'angular' has no exported member 'ui'.
src/core.config.ts(19,16): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/core.config.ts(37,43): error TS2305: Module 'angular' has no exported member 'ui'.
src/core.controller.ts(6,80): error TS2305: Module 'angular' has no exported member 'material'.
```

My tsconfig file looks like this:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "module": "system",
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "removeComments": true,
  "preserveConstEnums": true,
  "outFile": "out.min.js",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "typeRoots": [
   "./node_modules/@types"
  ],
 "types": [
  "angular",
  "angular-material",
  "angular-ui-router"
 ]
},
"files": ["file.ts"]
}
```

I tried to add reference paths (`/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/angular-material/index.d.ts" />`) for the definition files but it didn't help. I feel like i'm doing something wrong but i couldn't find out what. Does someone know what i am missing?

*edit*

I found out that i only get the errors when i compile with the use of my tsconfig.json file. When i use `tsc core.config.ts`, there are no errors, but with files: ["core.config.ts"] in my tsconfig file i get the same errors as seen above.

Comment: Did you install `@types/angular`?

Comment: Yes i did install it. I also tried to uninstall and installing it again but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
// <reference path="node_modules/@types/angular-material/index.d.ts" />
```

To

```
/// <reference types="angular" />
/// <reference types="angular-material" />
```

And add additional lines for the various modules you are referencing.

Unfortunately there is no official documentation for this yet but it is on the to-do list. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/348

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried to use this, but unfortunately it did not work. But i did find this: it only happens when i compile with the use of my tsconfig.json file. When i use `tsc core.config.ts`, there are no errors, but with files: ["core.config.ts"] in my tsconfig file i get the same errors as in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to module definitions referencing ("/// ...")
you need to import angular to make it visible like

```
/// <reference types="angular" />
/// <reference types="angular-material" />
import * as angular form "angular"
import {material, extend, IPromise, IDeferred} from "angular";
```

...

```
angular.extend(...);
extend(); // Note: that is a shortcut to angular.extend; see the second import
private $mdDialog: material.IDialogService;
var service: (value: any): IPromise<any> {...}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I use typings and I had the same problem.
To resolve this I just added angular-material in my typings.json file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#dc9dabe74a5be62613b17a3605309783a12ff28a",
    "angular-ui-router": "registry:dt/angular-ui-router#1.1.5+20160707113237",
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160627105203",
    "angular-material": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angular-material/angular-material.d.ts#2d0a1b1502610025bd55ce8eaa48069da8a16c82",
    "angular-mocks": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts#dc9dabe74a5be62613b17a3605309783a12ff28a",
    "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#dc9dabe74a5be62613b17a3605309783a12ff28a",
    "require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160316155526",
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160602141504"
  }
}
```

After that I run 'typings install', and that's all. I hope it will help you.